# iOS 8: Game Stuck on Loading Screen

Tags: ios, iphone, unity-game-engine

I created a game in Unity that work fine on iOS 7 and prior version. After updating to iOS 8 on my device my game stuck on loading screen and I receive the following log at console.

```
 <Error>: assertion failed: 12A365: libxpc.dylib + 51947 [ACFE5F1E-68D9-3D24-9B65-D604403A9625]: 0x7d
```

According to my game logic that could be the place in unity where I tried to switch the scene. Can any one please help me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the rep to comment, but have you performed a fresh new build or an append build? Try to do a replacement build and see if that resolves it.

Otherwise, create a brand new project with just a simple object in the scene and maybe a button to load a new scene and see if you still have issues. If no issues from this simple build, then it's likely to be a plug-in that's causing the problem in your project and becomes a process of elimination to find the culprit.